# Is this kind of mistake I made in my bachelor thesis a serious thing?

Tags: soft-question, education, publishing

A couple of days ago I handed in my bachelor thesis. Unfortunately I found a mistake in two of my definitions. This definitions were recursive ones so I forgot to write $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ instead of $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The definitions don't make sense for $n=1$. Would this be a big thing for my professor ? I just can't understand why some mistakes kind of seem impossible to find until you hand in your bachelor thesis... it drives me crazy.

Comment: As long as the underlying mathematics is fine (proofs of theorems etc still go through), I suspect that this shouldn't be too big a deal. It seems more like a typo than anything else.

Comment: It's gonna be fine. If you are too afraid,write a corrigendum in a twit(it seems it will fit the 150 characters).

Comment: If I'd worry all the time whenever I do mistakes like this, I wouldn't be happy again ^^

Comment: The underlying mathematics is completely fine I think, just like the proofs. I have the fear that the professor somehow doesn't see the big picture because of this careless mistakes or that he doesn't understand the definition or the purpose of the definition because of such mistakes.

Comment: Given how common errata such as this are in textbooks I would assume they are common elsewhere too. Typically I'm able to correct such errors from context and it rarely impedes understanding of the material.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it. Your thoughts and ideas are the substance of your thesis. Spelling, grammar, and [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) errors are unavoidable side-effects of recording your thoughts and ideas in writing. We only try to minimize those side-effects as courtesy to readers anyways, and we (or editors or reviewers) help stamp those errors out if/when the writing gets published.